# Operation is not allowed when the object is closed (Object is not closed)

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic, adodb

The following code, is generating that error.

```
Set getList = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
getList.ActiveConnection=EV_WikiConn
getList.Prepared = true
getList.commandtext= "declare @Lookup table(Id int identity(1, 1) , SongTitle nvarchar(512) ) 
insert into @Lookup(SongTitle)select * from ( values ('Deuce')) as x(a) 
select A.AlbumName, S.SongTitle , S.Writers , S.Vocals , S.SID , S.TheTime 
from Albums A inner join Songs S on A.AID = S.AID inner join @Lookup L on L.SongTitle = S.SongTitle order by L.Id"
set rsList = getList.execute
while not rsList.eof ' Error is on this line here.
```

I added this code here

```
Set getList = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
getList.ActiveConnection=EV_WikiConn
getList.Prepared = true
getList.commandtext= "declare @Lookup table(Id int identity(1, 1) , SongTitle nvarchar(512) ) 
insert into @Lookup(SongTitle)select * from ( values ('Deuce'),('Strutter'),('Parasite')) as x(a) 
select A.AlbumName, S.SongTitle , S.Writers , S.Vocals , S.SID , S.TheTime 
from Albums A inner join Songs S on A.AID = S.AID inner join @Lookup L on L.SongTitle = S.SongTitle order by L.Id"
set rsList = getList.execute
If rsList.State <> adStateOpen Then
While rsList.State <> adStateOpen
Set rsList = rsList.NextRecordset

rsList.movenext
wend
end if
```

This makes it run, however, I only get one record, instead of the 10 that is in the actual form. So, this is not going to work, but wanted to show what I have tried so far.

Comment: Please add the code where you are getting one record, the part within the `while not rsList.eof` loop

Comment: Both codes are there now. The bottom code, is the one that only gives one record, even though there is 3 that supposed to be shown in this example.

Comment: Joining on Song Title is never going to be a good idea, what happens if the title is adjusted? Use ids where possible to form unique relationships, textual ones are never a good idea. Does the `Songs` table not have a unique id for each song you could use instead of `SongTitle`?

Comment: I also like how you are arguing with ADODB, it reports the `Operation is not allowed when the object is closed` but you say it isn't closed, to be honest I'll always take ADOs word over the operator, if it says it's closed it's closed. That error was probably caused by not specifying `SET NOCOUNT ON` as the first operator will be seen as an empty recordset and cause the issue. By calling `NextRecordset` you are ignoring the first recordset and there by avoiding the error. As for only 1 record returning that's likely due to your query, have you tested in SSMS first?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ADODB.Recordset error '800a0e78' Operation is not allowed when the object is closed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19429061/adodb-recordset-error-800a0e78-operation-is-not-allowed-when-the-object-is-clo)

Comment: @Lankymart, absolutely NOT a duplicate question. As I did not ask that other question. And that other question, does not have the outcome that this one has.

Comment: Your actual issue was indeed that, but I failed to notice you weren't looping through the recordset so of course you'll only get 1 record! As for not being the same it is EXACTLY the same, that error is caused by trying to call `MoveNext` on a closed recordset. So whether you think it's a duplicate or not because your outcome was different is irrelevant.

Comment: Yea, I did not catch on to that either. I was trying so many different things, that I started getting confused in my coding. As the original code was using the .....While Not rsList.eof... And then I found the other code, and I just replaced it, instead of adding it to the mix. You live you learn...

Also, if you would have told me that it was caused by: trying to call MoveNext.... Then I would have caught onto it last night.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, got it all figured out. below is the code that was used, with a few notes in the code, to show what I did to make it work.

```
Set getList = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
getList.ActiveConnection=EV_WikiConn
getList.Prepared = true
getList.commandtext = _
    "SET NOCOUNT ON " & _
    "declare @Lookup table(Id int identity(1, 1) , " & _
    "SongTitle nvarchar(512) ) " & _
    "insert into @Lookup(SongTitle)select * from " & _
    "( values ('Hotter_Than_Hell'), ('Firehouse'), ('She'), " & _
    "('Parasite'), ('Nothin''_To_Lose')) as x(a) " & _
    "select A.AlbumName, S.SongTitle , S.Writers , S.Vocals , " & _
    "S.SID , S.TheTime from Albums A inner join " & _
    "Songs S on A.AID = S.AID inner join " & _
    "@Lookup L on L.SongTitle = S.SongTitle order by L.Id"

' the SET NOCOUNT ON, was added, but did not resolve the issue, I just left it in.
' The next 3 lines is what fixed the issue.
While rsList.State <> adStateOpen
    Set rsList = rsList.NextRecordset
Wend
While Not rsList.EOF%>

<%=rsList("SongTitle")%>

<%rsList.movenext
wend
rsList.Close
set rsList = nothing
```

Comment: Missed you weren't looping the recordset, which would cause only 1 record to return. Still recommend you build more robust relationships in the SQL though joining on `SongTitle` is asking for trouble.

Comment: Are you referring to this.............L.SongTitle = S.SongTitle...............
SongTitle only exist in one table. Not 2 tables, this is not comparing 2 values from 2 different tables... The L = @Lookup

Comment: Regardless linking on textual fields is bad practice.

Comment: OK, Lankymart. Let me explain this to you. The information is coming in from a textarea, it is being filtered through this SQL Query, it creates the Lookup table, with the names of the songs. Now, there is NO ID, so there is NO WAY that you can match an ID to something that is not provided to begin with. The next thing that is done, is once the names (Titles of the songs) passes through to the Lookup table (Temp table), it then matches them values with the values inside of the Real Songs Table. And then we get our match. THIS IS NOT Bad practice..

Comment: Whatever, personally it would be time for a redesign.

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of what the OP believes this is a duplicate of

[ADODB.Recordset error '800a0e78' Operation is not allowed when the object is closed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19429061/692942)

If we analyse the [original code revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/35262338/1) *(ignoring the hard wrap which will cause an error in VBScript)*

```
Set getList = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
getList.ActiveConnection=EV_WikiConn
getList.Prepared = true
getList.commandtext= "declare @Lookup table(Id int identity(1, 1) , SongTitle nvarchar(512) ) 
insert into @Lookup(SongTitle)select * from ( values ('Deuce')) as x(a) 
select A.AlbumName, S.SongTitle , S.Writers , S.Vocals , S.SID , S.TheTime 
from Albums A inner join Songs S on A.AID = S.AID inner join @Lookup L on L.SongTitle = S.SongTitle order by L.Id"
set rsList = getList.execute
while not rsList.eof ' Error is on this line here.
```

You can see that the original issue is the lack of

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
```

to stop the closed `ADODB.Recordset` object being returned for the initial `INSERT` operation.

The subsequent edits the OP makes confuses the issue, before this adding `SET NOCOUNT ON;` would have fix the problem without needing further changes.

The [next revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/35262338/3) is where the confusion begins  *(again, ignoring the hard wrap which will cause an error in VBScript)*

```
Set getList = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
getList.ActiveConnection=EV_WikiConn
getList.Prepared = true
getList.commandtext= "declare @Lookup table(Id int identity(1, 1) , SongTitle nvarchar(512) ) 
insert into @Lookup(SongTitle)select * from ( values ('Deuce'),('Strutter'),('Parasite')) as x(a) 
select A.AlbumName, S.SongTitle , S.Writers , S.Vocals , S.SID , S.TheTime 
from Albums A inner join Songs S on A.AID = S.AID inner join @Lookup L on L.SongTitle = S.SongTitle order by L.Id"
set rsList = getList.execute
If rsList.State <> adStateOpen Then
While rsList.State <> adStateOpen
Set rsList = rsList.NextRecordset

rsList.movenext
wend
end if
```

Let's just dissect this part

```
If rsList.State <> adStateOpen Then
While rsList.State <> adStateOpen
Set rsList = rsList.NextRecordset

rsList.movenext
wend
end if
```

First the `If` and `While` loop do the same thing accept the `While` does it repeatedly until the condition is met, making the `If` completely irrelevant.
The `While` loop checks for the current state of the `ADODB.Recordset` which without `SET NOCOUNT ON;` is returned as `adStateClosed` *(due to the `INSERT` operation)*. This is fine but by changing the `While` loop from

```
while not rsList.eof
```

to

```
While rsList.State <> adStateOpen
```

the condition has been changed and the `While` is no longer checking for `rsList.EOF` which would be the case when we are enumerating the `ADODB.Recordset` object. However, now it is only checking for the `.State` of `rsList` which once `.NextRecordset` is called will exit the loop as a open `ADODB.Recordset` object has been returned. Because the condition has been met the loop will only run once calling `.MoveNext` once and only returning one record.

So to summaries using

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
```

initially would have negated this whole scenario but hey [*"I don't understand the code"*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35262338/operation-is-not-allowed-when-the-object-is-closed-object-is-not-closed#comment58343658_35313932) apparently.

Comment: Seriously, NOW, you want to add in stuff, that should have been added in before I provided the working code. AN, you are totally wrong....... THIS SET NOCOUNT ON.......DID NOT fix the problem,Did you not read what I wrote. Dude, you have a problem, your code is WRONG!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @WayneBarron Just read the answer, then maybe you'll understand but with your abrasive nature I doubt it. `SET NOCOUNT ON;` will work it's been proven time and again I write this stuff in my sleep. I only felt the need to post this after your targeted nonsensical ramblings, to prove I do understand the code, it seems however you don't!